# MVC Ajax Edit button from partial view to re render other partial view

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

So I have 2 `partial views` in my main view: A `gridView` and a `roundPanel`.

So when the "Edit" button in my `Gridview` row is hit, the `roundPannel` should update with the info of the row.

My Edit button:

```
Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "EditConfig", new { id = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "QueueMonitorConfigurationsID") }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "configs" })
```

The function it calls:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditConfig(int id)
{
    StorageConfigurationModel resultForPanel = new StorageConfigurationModel { };
    IEnumerable<StorageConfigurationModel> configList = (IEnumerable<StorageConfigurationModel>)Session["ConfigurationList"];
    foreach (StorageConfigurationModel configModel in configList)
    {
        if (configModel.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID == id)
        {
            resultForPanel = configModel;
            break;
        }
    }
    return PartialView("cbpnlNewUpdateConfigs", resultForPanel);
}
```

Every time I click "Edit", a new view is open, when I just want to refresh the `roundPanel`(`partialview`).

Answer (score 3):

I call my controller through an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: { data1: 'data1' },
    success: function (result) {
        $(".Content").html(result);
    }
});
```

Doing it this way I replace the contents of a div with the partial view that is returned from the controller.  I don't know if it will make a difference but my method for the partial view I return PartialViewResult instead of ActionResult.  Hopefully this helps.